# Correctly init NSCoder in sub class when init NSCoder is convenience method in base class in Swift

Tags: swift, nscoder

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation


class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {

var name: String



init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String

    self.init(name: name)

}  
}


class Martin: Person {

 init() {
    self.init(name: "Martin")
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}

let p = Martin()

print(p.name)
```

For some reason I always end-up in a catch-22 situation, the only way i see making this work is to explicitly initialize all properties in `required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to able to remove the convenience and do `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` in `Martin`

I read about the init rules in Swift, still don't understand why `Martin` can't inherit the convenience init from `Person` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [the rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) state that

> 1. A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.
> 2. A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.
> 3. A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.

Comment: So there is no way of making it work without making `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` a non-convenience method? I thought using Rule 2 i could make it work somehow.  
  
Rule 2  
  
`If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.`

Comment: as always the solution is quite simple:  
    `class Martin: Person {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "Martin")
    }
    
    }`  
this way Martin is inheriting all the parent's initalizers